# How to override a CSS class within a content div

Tags: html, css, class, overriding

I want to reimplement the property margin-right in a bloc whitin a content.

this is the content id css:

```
#content h2 {
      margin-right:2px;
            }
```

this is the bloc class css:

```
    .bloc h2 {
margin-right:0px;
                }
```

I want the margin-right of the ".bloc" css fires rather than the "#content" css

Comment: It will help if you post your corresponding html as well.

Comment: The most specific CSS rule available will be used.  So you need to decide how to reference the different elements in a very DOM-specific manner.

Can you assign a class or ID to the h2 tag - or do you only have control over the containing div?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try !important, like this:

```
.bloc h2 
{
    margin-right:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not that good idea: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 8):

You could try this :

```
#content .bloc h2
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure I understood your question perfectly well, especially the last sentence...